# Remove Decimals without Rounding Power Q

Tags: powerquery

How to remove decimals without rounding in Power query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column,  custom column

```
= Number.IntegerDivide([ColumnNameHere],1)
```

or transform the column to remove decimals

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere",{{"ColumnNameGoesHere", each  Number.IntegerDivide(_,1),type number}})
```

or transform data type of column to whole number